# How does array offset access actually work

Tags: arrays, c

We all are aware of how easy it is to access elements of an array in the blink of an eye:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[10];
   
    array[5]=6;  //setat operation at index 5

    printf("%d",array[5]);  //getat operation
}
```

Yea, question may sound a bit stupid but how does a compiler just get you the index that you want to access for inserting data or for displaying it, so fast. Does it traverse to that index on its own for completing setat(),getat() operations.

Cause general means are: if you are asked to pick 502th element from a row of 1000 units, you would start counting until u get the count 502 (in case of computer 501) so is this the same happening in computer.

Comment: You're title is completely misleading, making it seems as though there are getat and setat methods in the question by appending parentheses

Comment: C isn't a very high-level language. When you index into an array, that's literally what you do. The code will access memory at an offset from the pointer pointing to the first element of the array. There is no `getat` or `setat`, adding function calls for a simple pointer+offset lookup would be silly. In general, implementing a homogeneous array as a linked list doesn't make much sense in anything low-level.

Comment: array[5] = 6. You know the start address "array" (eg: 100) and the size of each element (int=4) so u can just do 100 + 4*5 and end up at the memory location of the specific element 5, then put a 6 there

Comment: "you would start counting" Perhaps that's what *you* would do. This is also what a classical Turing machine would do. A Turing machine has a tape. In order to access cell 502 on the tape, you need to go to cell 1, then cell 2, ..., then cell 501. Modern computers don't work this way. They have this thing called RAM. RAM stands for "random access memory". "Random" here means that it provides access to any address equally fast. You give it the number 502, and bam, it returns you what is in the cell number 502 without counting to 502 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is stored in random-access memory (RAM). RAM is is divided into equal-sized, individually addressable units, such as bytes. Addressable means enumerable by an address, which is a number. Random access means that the processor doesn't have to traverse addresses 0 through 499 in order to access location 500. It directly proceeds to 500. How it works is that the computer places a binary representation of the adress 500 onto a collection of signal lines called the "address bus".  All of the devices connected to the address bus simultaneously examine the address and their circuitry answers the question "is this address in my range?". The device for which the answer is yes, then springs into action.

In the case of RAM it circuitry further decodes the address to determine which row and column of which bank to activate. The values read out are placed onto the data bus for the processor to collect.  The actual implementation is considerably more complicated due to caching, but that's the basic idea.

The main idea is that the machine accesses memory and memory-like resources (such as I/O ports) using an address, and the address is distributed, as a set of electrical signals, in parallel to all of the devices, which can look at it at once; and those devices themselves have parallel circuitry to further analyze the address to identify a specific resource within their innards. So addressing happens very fast, without having to search through resources that are not being addressed.

C language arrrays are a very low-level concept. A C array sits at some address in  memory and holds equal sized objects. These objects are accessed by performing arithmetic. For instance if the array elements are 8 bytes wide, then accessing the 17th element means that the machine has to multiply 17 x 8 to produce the offset 136, which is then added to the address of the array to produce the address of the element.

In youor program you have the expression `array[5]`.  The value `5` is known to the C compiler at compile time (before the program is translated, linked and executed). The size of the array elements, which are of type `int` is also known at compile time. The address of `array` isn't known at compile time. Therefore the offset calculation likely takes place at compile time; the `5` is converted to a `sizeof (int) * 5` offset calculated at compile time to a value like 20, which is then added to the address of `array` at run-time to calculate the address of `array[5]` and fetch its value from that address.